# How to fix this bug when creating this trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I created two triggers that are almost the same.

The triggers look like this:

**Trigger 1**

```
delimiter !!
drop trigger if exists updated_movie !!
create trigger update_movie after update on movie

for each row 

begin

    insert into movie_modification
    values (old.id, old.title, old.id_director, old.year, old.duration, old.country, old.movie_facebook_likes, old.imdb_score, old.gross, old.budget, true);

end !!
delimiter ;
```

**Trigger 2**

```
delimiter !!
drop trigger if exists inserted_movie !!
create trigger inserted_movie after insert on movie

for each row

begin

    insert into movie_modification
    values (new.id_movie, new.title, new.id_director, new.year, new.duration, new.country, new.movie_facebook_likes, new.imdb_score, new.gross, new.budget, false);

end !!
delimiter ;
```

As I changed some things on the triggers, I had to drop them and create them a couple of times. Now that I have the final format for my triggers I execute all the second trigger (`inserted_movies`) and it drops and creates again successfully.

But when I execute the first one (`updated_movies`) I get the following output and error:

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1360 Trigger does not exist
>   Error Code: 1359. Trigger already exists

Isn't MySQL contradicting itself? I don't understand why does this happen just to one of the triggers. They are both almost the same.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `updated_movie` !== `update_movie` Just a little Typo Dropping one and creating the other

Comment: oh... I'm dumb. Thanks @RiggsFolly

Comment: Haha well its late here so we will assume its late there too :)

Comment: I am upvoting this. It may have been a typo, but it was clear and complete, which is more than we can say for questions from 90% of new users at Stack Overflow. Good effort.

Comment: Haha! Thanks, for next question it won't be any typo issue, I promise. As Riggs said, it's late here too